# How to pass parameter using select in bash

Tags: bash, select, parameters, menu, getopt

I'm trying to create a bash script that lets the user use both a menu style and also a command line switch style interface. I was wondering if there was a way to pass a parameter to a menu option in `select` as if it were just an argument to a script. For example, in my script I can specify a file to move to my junk folder by saying `junk -d file.txt`. But if the user does not specify any params it should use the `select` option. i.e. `1) move file 2) clear junk folder 3) watch folder` etc.

On this menu, I want to be able to write the option and then send an argument to that option. Like `1 filetobemoved.txt`. I have tried putting `$OPTARG` after the method that gets called by the menu but this doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code I have for the menu at the moment, I'm trying to call the recover method and pass an argument (the filename) to it.

```
if (( $# == 0 ))
then if (( $OPTIND == 1 )) 
 then select menu_list in list recover delete total watch kill exit
     do case $menu_list in
     "list") list;;
     "recover") recover $GETOPT;;
     "delete") delete;;
     "total") total;;
     "watch") _watch;;
     "kill") _kill;;
     "exit") exit 0;;
     *) echo "unknown option";;
     esac
  done
fi
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code that executes the cases in a function. Then you can check for the command line option and skip the `select`, and just call the function.

```
do_command() {
    case "$1" in
     "list") list;;
     "recover") recover $GETOPT;; # had -a after recover
     "delete") delete;;
     "total") total;;
     "watch") _watch;;
     "kill") _kill;;
     "exit") exit 0;;
     *) echo "unknown option";;
    esac
}
if (($# == 0))
then if (( $OPTIND == 1 )) 
    then select menu_list in list recover delete total watch kill exit
         do do_command "$menu_list"
         done
    fi
elif [[ "$1" = "-d" ]]
then do_command delete
...
fi
```